# Files and Folders appear in Eclipse inside the "Referenced Libraries" category. How to prevent this behavior?

Tags: java, eclipse

I've inherited an Eclipse project in which a lot of the data is in the "Referenced Libraries" category, although for all good purposes they show up just as regular files / directories in the file system. Adding new files to the project yields a similar result -- they'll get thrown into the "Referenced Libraries" category.

I'd like to turn this weirdo-project into something more akin to the usual Eclipse java project experience, having `Flasji`'s contents inside `src/`. How?

[image]

### Edit ##:

Here are my .classpath file's contents as requested:

```
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="alloy4.2-rc.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="asm-2.2.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="bsh-2.0b4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="commons-io-2.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="congu.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="Gent java6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="junit-4.10.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: Post your .classpath for analysis. You should probably just remove an offending entry there.

Comment: Change your buildpath of your project in eclipse and add other folder as source folder that should solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid if these visually, open your MANIFEST.MF and in the editor click on the third tab "Runtime" on that editor page there is a classpath section and you will see the jars there, if you remove them in the editor your classpath will get auto updated and the referenced libraries will no longer exist.